# reshaping rows and columns and then converting to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, svm, reshape

Following DataFrame contains integer values. I want them to reshaped into a new column where every row will be represented, as a combination of each 3 rows of each columns from old dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [123, 456, 789, 321, 654, 987, 1234, 45678],
                     'column2': [123, 456, 789, 321, 654, 987, 1234, 45678]})
data=data.astype(str) #string conv.
n = len(data) // 3 #reshaping to new DF
# Create a new DataFrame without commas
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'vector': [' '.join(data.iloc[i:i+3, :].values.flatten()) for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
})

Output:
    vector
    0  123 123 456 456 789 789
    1  321 321 654 654 987 987
    2    1234 1234 45678 45678
```

Now this datframe contans 'str' values. Is it possible to convert this datframe to 'int' again. Beacuse, I want to use this into SVM algorithm as numpy array, where it consider this dataframe as error due to 'str' object. I was unable to convert it to 'int' again, or is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attain the same result in a more idiomatic way by `apply`ing a concatenating function to every group formed after splitting the dataframe into `n=3` consecutive rows. No need to cast to `str` in the middle:

```
def concat(x):                                                                                                       
    return pd.concat([x.T[c] for c in x.T]).to_list()                                                                
                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
new = data.groupby(data.index // 3).apply(concat)                                                                    
print(new)
```

gives

```
0    [123, 123, 456, 456, 789, 789]
1    [321, 321, 654, 654, 987, 987]
2        [1234, 1234, 45678, 45678]
dtype: object
```

In the resulting dataframe (actually a `Series`), the value is of the type returned by `concat`, in my example a `list`. For other types, convert appropriately, e.g. `.to_numpy()`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, as dtype remains 'object', due to list; is there any other way to convert DF into int32/int64? Because i can't put this as object into the SVM algorithm.

Comment: As my answer explains, for other datatypes you can just change the return type of `concat`. By removing `.to_list()`, you'll see that `new` is now of `dtype` equal to `int64` (its type is still a `Series`).